# A communication error occurred within the Reporting Services endpoint on this SharePoint site

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm with 2 app servers and 3 web front-ends. I'm using Reporting Services in SharePoint Mode. I have the report service installed on one app server. I also installed the add-in on this server. I've also installed the Add-In on all the front-ends. So the other app server doesn't have anything related to reporting services installed.

The problem is that sometimes on the first report request of a new browser session, I'm receiving a **HTTP/1.1 500 A communication error occurred within the Reporting Services endpoint on this SharePoint site. If the error persists, contact the SharePoint site administrator for help.** If I hit the refresh button, the report renders fine and will continue to render fine until I kill the browser and try again. This is happening for many of my users.

Any ideas what could be the cause? I'm wondering if I have to install the report service and add-in on the other app server. MSDN doesn't specify if it's required or not. Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479774.aspx shows that I didn't really need to install the add-in on the app server, but I don't think that's the problem.